# Tag summaries are oblivious to tag linking syntax: [tag:this-thing]

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

We've recently added a summary for the [time-management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management) which includes references to the tags [timing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timing) and [time-travel](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel), using the very same fancy tag markup I used just now.

The syntax doesn't get parsed though and just shows up in plain text. Go look at the tag summary right now above the questions, or look at the autocomplete for it in the [Ask Question page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You'll see what I mean. I've opted not to edit it further just so you can see this happening (not a huge problem since the tag is only rarely used).

---

I imagine the best case scenario for the fix would be that we see [time-travel](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) this fancy thing. In the autocomplete dropdown it should probably do nothing but look pretty - it *could* insert the mentioned tag instead, but this could lead to confusion and errors if someone clicks on that box to pick that tag for the suggestion, and accidentally click on a link to another tag mentioned in that description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summaries do not allow *anything* fancy. They are plain text only, and very much by design. That's also why you do not see a preview for the the excerpt when editing the tag wiki, unlike for the main content – there's nothing to preview.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)